# Can't run HMA OpenVPN in Docker

Tags: docker, vpn, openvpn

Does anybody have any experience running HMA in Docker container?

When I run this command

```
openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/UK.London_LOC1S1.UDP.ovpn
```

I see

```
Sat Jan 14 16:38:44 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=UK/ST=London/L=London/O=Privax_Ltd/OU=HMA_Pro_VPN/CN=hidemyass.com/emailAddress=info@privax.com
Sat Jan 14 16:38:44 2017 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Sat Jan 14 16:38:44 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=UK/ST=London/L=London/O=Privax_Ltd/OU=HMA_Pro_VPN/CN=server/emailAddress=info@privax.com
...
Sat Jan 14 16:38:48 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

but I'm not able to load anything.

I've been running HMA OpenVPN on my Vagrant machine for a while with pretty much the same configuration. Is there anything specific to docker that might have missed?

I'm running my machine with `privileged` argument.

```
docker run -ti --rm --privileged my_image /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also need `--net=host` if you do not add this to your `docker run` command, you container does not communicate with the network devices of the host, so it can't work.

I have a similar OpenVPN container and I start it with

`docker run -d --net=host --name myvpn --privileged -p 1194:1194/udp my_alpine_vpn`